# Using @ngrx/store in Angular 2 application

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have tried to implement the example mentioned in [here](https://github.com/ngrx/store) to understand
the basics of @ngrx/store.

Below is my implemented code

Reducer "counter.cs" code

```
import { Action , ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
export const DECREMENT = 'DECREMENT';
export const RESET = 'RESET';


 export const counterReducer: ActionReducer<number> = (state: number = 0 ,action: Action ) => {

    switch(action.type) {
      case INCREMENT: 
        return state + 1;
      case DECREMENT:
        return state - 1;
      case RESET:
        return 0;  
      default:
        return state;    
     }

   }
```

Feature module code //rx.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { counterReducer } from './counter';
import { StoreComponent } from './store.component';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
              RouterModule.forChild([   
             {path:'store' , component: StoreComponent}
             ]),
             StoreModule.provideStore({counter: counterReducer}),
             CommonModule
            ],
   providers: [],
   exports:[],
   declarations:[StoreComponent]
})

export class RxModule { }
```

and here is the component code

// component code store.component.ts

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { INCREMENT , DECREMENT , RESET } from './counter';

 interface AppState {
counter: number;
 }

 @Component({
 selector:'',
 template: `
 <h2> ngrx/store Example </h2>

  Current state : {{counter | async }}
  <input type="button" (click)="increment()" value="Increment"><br>
  <input type="button" (click)="decerment()" value="Decrement">

   `
 })

 export class StoreComponent {

  counter: Observable<number>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
     this.counter = this.store.select('counter');
  }

   increment() {
  this.counter = this.store.dispatch({ type: INCREMENT });
   }

   decerment() {
  this.counter = this.store.dispatch({type: DECREMENT});
   }
  }
```

Compiling this code gives me below error

> Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>     Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.

and this error points to below line of code in store.component.ts

```
this.counter = this.store.select('counter');
```

Any idea what is the issue.

Comment: What versions of TypeScript and ngrx/store are you using? I don't see the error. Also, what if you explicitly specify the type? Like this: `this.counter = this.store.select<number>('counter');`

Comment: 1. Typescript : 2.0.3 and  @ngrx/store : 2.2.1

2. yes adding <number> fixed the issue , but now I am getting error for this.counter = this.store.dispatch({ type: INCREMENT }); line ..any idea what needs to be modified

Comment: and the error is "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Observable<number>'"

Comment: `dispatch` returns `void`. I think you should spend some time with the [documentation](https://github.com/ngrx/store#introduction) and [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app).

Comment: Thanks for your help.

1. first issue got resolved after installing the version you suggested.
2. second issue was my mistake , removed the assignment part